# VBA - Compare data from WB1 to WB2 and copy unique data from WB1 to WB2

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to compare the C Columns from Workbook 1 and Workbook 2.

Workbook 1 contains all the data from Workbook 2 with a few additional entries scattered about the column.

Any unique data found in Workbook 1's (C Column) I want to copy to Workbook 2 in the correct order.

Thank you for any help you can offer!

At the moment this is what I have. I'm just trying to change the color of a cell to test the functionality of the code:

```
Private Sub Test1_Click()
' Compare data from both worksheets
Dim varSheetA As Variant
Dim varSheetB As Variant
Dim strRangeToCheck As String
Dim strRangeToCheckB As String
Dim iRow As Long
Dim iCol As Long
Dim WBSource As String
Dim WBTarget As String
Dim WSSource As String
Dim WSTarget As String
Dim wbkA As Object
Dim LRN As String

' Counts the active Rows in a spreadsheet
    LRN = C & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

' Set Values
    WBTarget = untext.Value   'untext is workbook 2 file location
    WBSource = extext.Value   'extext is workbook 1 file location

' Set Worksheets
    WSSource = "AD_6517_UTC_SIK_ENG_ME_FP_SIKCR"
    WSTarget = "WBS Reference"

' Open Workbook
    Set wbkA = Workbooks.Open(WBTarget)

' Set Range
    strRangeToCheck = Workbooks(WBTarget).Worksheets(WSTarget).Range("[@[Task Number]]")
    strRangeToCheckB = Workbooks(WBSource).Worksheets(WSSource).Range("[@[task_name]]")

' If you know the data will only be in a smaller range, reduce the size of the ranges above.
Debug.Print Now
varSheetA = Range(strRangeToCheck)
varSheetB = Range(strRangeToCheckB)
Debug.Print Now

For iRow = LBound(varSheetA, 1) To UBound(varSheetA, 1)
    For iCol = LBound(varSheetA, 2) To UBound(varSheetA, 2)
        If varSheetA(iRow, iCol) = varSheetB(iRow, iCol) Then
            ' Cells are identical.
            ' Do nothing.
            MsgBox ("MATCH")
        Else
            ' Cells are different.
            MsgBox ("ELSE STATEMENT")
            Application.run ("ColorChange")
        End If
    Next iCol
Next iRow

End Sub
```

Comment: please tell us what your code does **not** do that you want it to do or how it is not working as you wish.

Comment: Sorry, at the moment I keep getting:
Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range
It's happening here: 
  strRangeToCheck = Workbooks(WBTarget).Worksheets(WSTarget).Range("[@[Task Number]]")

Comment: on which line @Zachy?

Comment: It's happening on this line:

strRangeToCheck = Workbooks(WBTarget).Worksheets(WSTarget).Range("[@[Task Number]]")

Comment: That is because you are trying to pass a `Range` into a `String` variable. Change `Dim strRangeToCheck As String` to `Dim strRangeToCheck As Range` and it will work. (*You may want to change the `str` at the beginning to `rng`.*)

Comment: Hmm it's still giving me the same error after changing them to Range.

Comment: `WBTarget = untext.Value` `untext` is a named range?... check to see it's what you expect. Also, `Range("[@[Task Number]]")` is incorrect syntax.

Comment: untext is a textbox that takes the value of Workbook 2 file location.

And I tried changing the range to .Range(C2,LRN) but that doesn't seem to work either. Is there any alternative to placing the last active row here:
.Range(C2,***LastActiveRow***)

Comment: See [this](http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables) for working with Tables (ListObjects) in VBA. *(referring to [@[Task Number]])*

Comment: Thank you both for the help, I'll play around with it and let you know how I make out.